# Formularios dinámicos, pasar muchos valores y obtenerlos JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando enviar un formulario que crea los mismos campos dependiendo de cuantos div se elija a través de un input, en mejor contexto, se elijen cuantas pizzas se van a pedir y se crea un formulario con cada pizza y este tiene un select para escoger el tamaño de cada una, luego esto lo envío por url a otro documento html, pero me di cuenta que a pesar de tener el mismo name el selected, me lo manda por separado

Este es el código de mi formulario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese código se multiplica dependiendo de cuantas pizzas se escriban en un input relacionado, todos los select poseen el mismo name, quisiera saber si hay una forma de enviar el formulario y que los select vayan en un array para que no se vea una url tan saturada, ya que por ejemplo si se seleccionan 100 pizzas, se va a ver una url muy larga, como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Tambien usas php?, ¿donde esta tu formulario?  todos los selects deben ser nombrados diferentes en cuanto tenga los demas datos por favor respondeme  y con gusto intento ayudarte

Comment: No, debo utilizar únicamente JavaScript